# mailcore2 add important flag to message

Tags: ios, iphone, mailcore2

I am developing iphone email app. I am using mailcore2 library. Everything is working fine. I want to add 'important' flag while sending email. I have searched the web but did not find any help. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You're probably looking for that header: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4021#section-2.1.54

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes we have to set extraheader for it like [[builder header] setExtraHeaderValue:@"Important" forName:@"priority"];

Answer (score 0):

To set flags with sending email we have to set extra header for priority like this:

```
    [[builder header] setExtraHeaderValue:@"Important" forName:@"priority"];
```